# Can't create a post with a PDF document via LinkedIn rest/posts API

Tags: linkedin-api

I can't create a post with a PDF document via the rest/posts API. I'm getting a 201 Created response, but the post isn't showing up on the LinkedIn page. Using the LinkedIn web service, I can create posts with this PDF document. How can I fix this?

LinkedIn Version: 202306

X-Restli protocol version: 2.0.0

[image]

#linkedin

Answer (score 0):

After selected your .pdf file from ***Postman > Body > Binary***, send PUT request to the upload URL with these headers;

```
{
  Authorization: <your_access_token>
  X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0
  LinkedIn-Version: 202308
  Content-Type: application/pdf
}
```

---

Then you can check it's uploading status;

`GET https://api.linkedin.com/rest/documents/urn%3Ali%3Adocument%3AD4D10AQEre7VgR259d4`

> *PS: You should encode your URLs like this `:` -> `%3A`*

With these headers;

```
{
  Authorization: <your_access_token>
  X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0
  LinkedIn-Version: 202308
}
```

You should see something like this in response;

```json
{
    "downloadUrl": "https://media.licdn.com/dms/document/media/D4D10AQEre7VgR259d4/ads-document-pdf-analyzed/0/1709787864966",
    "owner": "urn:li:person:234adf34",
    "id": "urn:li:document:D4D10AQEre7VgR259d4",
    "downloadUrlExpiresAt": 1710396000000,
    "status": "AVAILABLE"
}
```

If status is **AVAILABLE** then it means your pdf file uploaded to LinkedIn successfully and it is ready to use.

You can now add the file ID to your post.